# Android How to handle Multiple Runnable objects at the same time

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I was trying to create multiple queues of tasks and execute them at the same time but with different delay time. Basically, at first I only have one runnable object

```
private final Runnable myQueue = new Runnable() {
public void run() {

    if (service != null && service.isRunning() && service.queueEmpty()) {
        queueTasks();
    }
    // run again in period defined in preferences
    new Handler().postDelayed(myQueue,getUpdatePeriod(prefs));
}
```

};

```
private void StartWExecute() {new Handler().post(myQueue);}
```

I want to improve my code so that there will be more than one queue, and all queues start executing at the same time, but each queue may have different updatePeriod depending on the task in it. In this way I can sort tasks into queues and manually control the update speed. How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: create a class that extends a `Handler` and override its `handleMessage`, now you can create multiple instances of your `Handler` class each having different delays / timing

Comment: @pskink hi thanks for your reply. I'm kind of new to android. Could you be more specific? maybe write an example please? Thank you.

Comment: something like [this](http://pastebin.com/pzdH6M4p)

Comment: If we use handler.postDelayed(runnableName, 100); statement multiple times with different runnable is this ok ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need use a **MessageQueue**:

1.Declare a Handler:
 `Handler mWorkerHandler;` 
2.Create a Looper:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                mWorkerHandler = new Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage - what = " + msg.what);
                    }
                };
                Looper.loop();
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

3.Now you can send any number messages and perform operations according to message content:

```
mWorkerHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 2000);
mWorkerHandler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
```

Comment: If we use handler.postDelayed(runnableName, 100); statement multiple times with different runnable is this ok ?